# Contact physics not working in SpriteKit for a platformer in Swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

For some reason the the collision box is off. When I run this the box that is supposed to be on does not collide with the drawn box. It looks like two boxes with space in between. Here is the platform code.

```
     platform = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.blackColor(), size: CGSize(width: 300, height: 500))

    platform?.position = CGPoint(x: 200, y: 0)
    platform?.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: self.size)
    platform?.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    platform?.physicsBody?.dynamic = false


    self.addChild(platform!)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating platform's physics body with a size of a scene (`self.size`).

What you need to do is:

```
platform?.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: platform.size)
```

Turn on physics visual representation in `viewDidLoad` method in your GameViewController.swift:

```
skView.showsPhysics = true
```

This will help you with visual debugging.

Comment: @ParalaxWobat You are welcome :) If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.